# Get new point Coordinate by Current Point and Angle and Distance in arcgis js

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm developing a Web GIS Application using arcgis javascript Api and I need to drawing line from point1 by distance and angle. first step calculate point2 by this formula

```
point2X = point1.x + distance * Math.cos(angle)
point2Y = point1.y + distance * Math.sin(angle)
```

> Distance unit 'Meter' and angle in 'radians'

Second Step: Draw line with point1 and point2. If the input distance is 1000 meters, the drawn line shows the length as 866 meters, when measured with arcgis measurement tool. Is coordinate system in this formula an impact?

> Function:

```
function GetNewPoint(x, y, distance, angle) {

        var alpha = ToRadian(angle);

        var cos = Math.cos(alpha);
        var sin = Math.sin(alpha);
        var x2 = (cos * distance)+x ;
        var y2 = (sin * distance)+y ;

        return esri.geometry.xyToLngLat(x2, y2);
    }
    function ToRadian(angle) {
        return (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
    }
```

Comment: can you add sample or js fiddle for it... whatever you have tried so far..

Comment: Well.. See there are different spatial reference projection so adding one common function will not work because like lat long or x, y  having different formats and they expect adding factor according... I want to understand exact scenario so I am asking for running code....

Answer (score 0):

The map projection (the thing that is defined by your coordinate system) will absolutely impact the result of the measure.

"Every map projection causes distortion of shapes, areas, directions, and/or distances. Some projections such as Robinson or Winkel Tripel attempt to minimize distortion across the world through some compromise of all those factors. Other projections (such as UTM and State Plane) are designed for focused areas of the globe in order to keep the distortion minimal."
source: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/05/measuring-distances-and-areas-when-your-map-uses-the-mercator-projection/

Fortunately, the Web API that you are using has some methods to re-project your data before you do any measurement.

If you are interested in re-project a specific feature of your map, you can use something like this:

```
var sr = new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:32610}) 

// assuming you already referenced geometryService
geometryService.project([graphic], sr, function(projectedGraphic){   
  geometryService.areasAndLengths(projectedGraphic, function(result){   
    var perimeter = result.lengths[0]; 
    var area = result.areas[0]; 
  }); 
});
```

The previous example assumes the usage of a geometry service (you can find this at ArcGIS Online or at your ArcGIS for Server Instance) and is remotely processed.

You can find more information about Geometry Service at [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geometryservice.html) link.

Let me know if this information helps to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [website](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) he put all the equation you need to work with coordiantes and **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174576/get-new-point-coordinate-by-current-point-coordinate-angle-and-distance-in-arcg/68196378#68196378)** is my solution to get the coordiantes of the new point.