# Get new point coordinate by current Point coordinate, angle and distance in arcgis js api 4.x

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis-js-api

I want to get `coordinate (x,y)` of a point **B** based on coordinate of point **A** and distance from the point **A** and an angle using Arcgis js API 4.x .

For example : i have point **A** in (a,b) the distance between **A** and **B** is 500m and the angle is 20°, how can i get (x,y) of **B**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fount the equation [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), i implemented it and it works perfectly.

this is my simple :

```
    const R = 6371e3; //rayon of the erth
    let lat1 = 36.7538 * Math.PI / 180; // latitude in rad
    let long1 = 3.0588 * Math.PI / 180; // longiture in rad
    let d = 5000; //distance between the two points
    let angle = (90-20)*Math.PI/180; // the angle between the 2 points in rad (20°)
    const sigma = d / R;
    const delLat = sigma * Math.cos(angle);
    let lat2 = (lat1 + delLat) * 180 / Math.PI;//latitude of the destination point
    const del = Math.log(Math.tan(lat2 / 2 + Math.PI / 4) / Math.tan(lat1 / 2 + Math.PI / 4));
    // const q = Math.abs(del) > 10e-12 ? delLat / del : Math.cos(lat1); 
    const q = Math.cos(lat1)
    
    const delLong = sigma * Math.sin(angle) / q;
    let long2 = (long1 + delLong) * 180 / Math.PI; //longitude of the destination point
```